# What achievements are "missable"? *spoilers*

Tags: achievements, saints-row-iv

So, I was looking for a list of achievements that I would be able to miss on my playthrough. Such as ones that fall within quests that aren't repeatable, or during one-time events.

> For example, when rescuing Matt Miller you can get the achievement "You Chose... Poorly" by picking the red door. But if you pick the blue door, you would miss it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the achievement you mentioned in spoiler markup, the other missable achievement is: **Saints & Sensibility**, where you have to had...

> Completed 'Grand Finale' with the full help of your homies.

To avoid missing that achievement...

> There are two endings to the [Grand Finale](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Finale) mission, though it is not through anything the player does in the mission. If all [loyalty quests](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row_IV#Loyalty) are completed, then the player will unlock the true ending where the Saints discover time travel and the narrator will be revealed to be Jane Austen. If not all the loyalty quests are completed, then the player gets the non-canonical "bad ending" of the game in which the Saints do not discover time travel and the player will not get the "Saints and Sensibility" achievement.
>
>  <sup>Source: [Saints Row Wiki, "**Grand Finale** - Trivia"](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Finale)</sup>

As for the Enter the Dominatrix DLC, since you can replay its missions, there are no missable achievements. You would have to finish the whole DLC to replay the missions, though. If you'd rather not do that, the ff. achievements are missable the first time around:

- **All Too Easy**

  > Kill Zinyak in less than 5 minutes in 'Save the Planet'.
- **Indomitable**

  > Complete 'Meet the Dominatrix' without dying.
- **Rigging the Race**

  > Destroy all the rival pony carts in 'At the Races'.
- **Health Inspector**

  > Destroy all the green polyps inside Paul in 'Pop His Top'.